# Query Tokens.Accounts storage function using py-substrate-interface

Tags: storage, python, py-substrate-interface

I'm trying to fetch asset balances in accounts for various assets using py-substrate-interface. I know I can query the `Tokens.Accounts` storage function but I'm not sure which params I need to pass to the query_map function to get the balances.

For example I want to get balances of `{"ForeignAsset":"5"}` on acala, how would the query_map function look like.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can be quitte cumbersome to compose complex params of certain storage functions, I generated composition examples for well-known runtimes (also for calls): https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-metadata-docs

In this specific case you can have a look at: https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-metadata-docs/acala/tokens/#accounts

Because you want to query a mapped storage function, you can omit params from right to left to get all results:

```python
result = substrate.query_map('Tokens', 'Accounts', ['24YtbsBQ2CG9e6MeF71aownnpHaU3y4VugVj7HzEmSacbofK'], max_results=10)

for token, account_info in result:
    print(f'{token.value}: {account_info.value}')
    # {'LiquidCrowdloan': 13}: {'free': 120800000000, 'reserved': 0, 'frozen': 0}
```

It is also possible to query multiple dimensions:

```python
result = substrate.query_map('Tokens', 'Accounts', max_results=10)

for (account, token), account_info in result:
    print(f'{account.value}: {token.value}: {account_info.value}')
    # 24YtbsBQ2CG9e6MeF71aownnpHaU3y4VugVj7HzEmSacbofK: {'LiquidCrowdloan': 13}: {'free': 120800000000, 'reserved': 0, 'frozen': 0}
```

Note the `max_results`, as this can result in many records.

**Edit**: However, because of the way the storage key is composed in Substrate, it is only possible to omit certain params in a strict order. So it is not possible to query a certain token without specifying the account first.